# Python "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'"

Tags: python

I'm writing this simple python program for school, where it takes a roman numeral and convert it into arab numbers.
E.g: I = 1, X = 10 etc

The program works fine when converting simple numbers, but he problem arises when it needs to convert the numbers that require subtraction. For example when "IV" is given as input, the program should print 4, instead it spits out an error code.

I've tried setting input as an int, however that just gave me a new error code. The weird thing is this worked when i handed it in, but when i later downloaded it back to my machine and removed the comments, it broke.
Also it's basically a copy paste of the teachers code, so yeah.

```
def omkodchiffer(c):
    if c == "I":
        return 1
    if c == "V":
        return 5
    if c == "X":
        return 10
    if c == "L":
        return 50
    if c == "C":
        return 100
    if c == "D":
        return 500
    if c == "M":
        return 1000


def omregn(t):
    arabertal = 0
    for i in range(0, len(t)):
        if i < len(t) - 1:
            if omkodchiffer(t[i]) < omkodchiffer(t[i + 1]):
                arabertal -= omkodchiffer(t[i])
                i += 1
            elif omkodchiffer(t[i]) >= omkodchiffer(t[i + 1]):
                arabertal += omkodchiffer(t[i])
                i += 1
        else:
            arabertal += omkodchiffer(t[i])
    return arabertal


omregnet = omregn(input("Indtast romertal her:").capitalize())
print(omregnet)
```

Expected result: For the program to print "4" when "IV" is given.
Actual result: Error code is printed

Comment: In one iteration, either `omkodchiffer(t[i])` or `omkodchiffer(t[i + 1])` is `None`.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code. In particular, eliminate things like manual input, use hardcoded values instead. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please do include the *full traceback* of exceptions, that makes it much easier for us to help you. In many cases, only with a full traceback can we help *at all*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
omregnet = omregn(input("Indtast romertal her:").capitalize())
```

You should not be using `capitalize` here. `capitalize` makes the first character of the string capital, and the rest lowercase. For example, `"IV".capitalize()` becomes `"Iv"`. This is a problem because `omkodchiffer` does not know how to handle lowercase V. So it returns None, and that None value is used in one of the inequalities in your conditionals, where it fails to compare sensibly to an integer.

Use `.upper()` instead.

```
omregnet = omregn(input("Indtast romertal her:").upper())
```